# How not to close browser after using selenium browser?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, browser, auto

How not to close browser after using selenium browser?

I made autologin code but want not to close the browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your webdriver object is in a function, try making it global.
For Example:

```py
def auto_login():
    global browser
    browser = webdriver.Safari()

    """
    rest of your code
    """
```